# mb_detect_encoding , PHP7.1.13 phpMyadmin not working Wamp windows

Tags: phpmyadmin, php-7.1, php-ini, php

I added php 7.1.13 version in wampp server windows, PHPmyadmin working perfect on php5.5.12 version. 
when 1 change my php version to 7.1.13 from my previous version 5.5.12 then phpmyadmin stop working.

`Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function mb_detect_encoding() in` `D:\wamp\apps\phpmyadmin4.1.14\libraries\php-gettext\gettext.inc:177 Stack trace:` `#0 D:\wamp\apps\phpmyadmin4.1.14\libraries\php-gettext\gettext.inc(279)`

i have uncomented `extension=php_mbstring.dll`,

i also enabled `;zend.multibyte = Off` to `zend.multibyte = on`

but error is same

[php7 php info screen short](https://i.stack.imgur.com/noqau.png)

it is still disable,
is it the real reason for this error??

Also including php extension window image[php extension screenshort](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ESJGi.jpg)

Also including php version image [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NSTu1.jpg)

i would be greatfull if any on will answer

Comment: I found solution for this issue 
i added this line in my php.ini file {extension_dir = "d:/wamp/bin/php/php7.1.13/ext/"}, give full path to extension directory
i also update my phpmyadmin version phpmyadmin4.1.14 is not compatible with php7